# Is there a simple way to make lists behave as files (with ftplib)

Tags: python, ftp, file-upload, list, iterator

I'd like to use ftplib to upload program-generated data as lists. The nearest method I can see for doing this is ftp.storlines, but this requires a file object with a readlines() method.

Obviously I could create a file, but this seems like overkill as the data isn't persistent.

Is there anything that could do this?:

```
session = ftp.new(...)
upload = convertListToFileObject(mylist)
session.storlines("STOR SOMETHING",upload)
session.quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use `StringIO` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO)), it is a memory buffer that is a file-like object.

```
from io import StringIO    # version < 2.6: from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
buffer.writelines(mylist)
buffer.seek(0)

session.storlines("...", buffer)
```

Note that the `writelines` method does not add line separators. So you need to make sure that each string in mylist ends with a `\n`. If the items in mylist do not end with a `\n`, you can do:

```
buffer.writelines(line + '\n' for line in mylist)
```

Comment: Note you would probably prefer the `cStringIO` module to the `StringIO` module (if you weren't using the `io` module).